# Ubuntu PIP Installs Packages Globally Instead of Inside VirtualEnv

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation, python, pip

I am trying to create a virtualenv and install packages from requirements.txt that I have with the project.

When I create the environment, I check that the python and pip indeed come from that enviroment. Namely, when I run:

`source ./virtualenv/bin/activate`

`which pip`

`which python`

I get results that point to the binaries located inside the virtualenv directory

I then proceed to install the packages:
`pip install -r requirements.txt`

For awhile, it was giving me trouble about the `pkg-resources=0.0.0` line within the requirements.txt. As it turned, that line is input into this file because of a bug in Ubuntu. As you can probably surmise, I had created this file on an Ubuntu machine.

Once I strike the line out, the installation proceeds.

However, when I run pip list after the installation, the list contains only

> pip (8.1.1) pkg-resources (0.0.0) setuptools (20.7.0)

What is more, if I deactivate the virtualenv and run pip list globally, I see that all of the dependencies were installed globally.

There are two questions here. One - that is most obious - why does it happen? The second one is how could I clean up my global packages and uninstall the pollutants which now reside there?

**Addendum:**

Yet another bizarre behavior consists of the following. When I try to run `sudo pip uninstall -r requirements.txt` from within the virtualenv with hopes of reversing the global installation, I get the following error:

> Cannot uninstall requirement aldryn-apphooks-config, not installed

That is, it appears that when I try to uninstall, pip tries to look for packages inside the virtualenv.

On the other hand, when I deactivate the virtualenv, I can successfully uninstall the packages from the global installation using the same command.

Somehow, there is a difference in how the pip install command works on Ubuntu when compared to the pip uninstall command. They "look" for packages in different places.

Comment: I had the exact same issue. I deactivated virtualenv switched to `root` and activated the virtualenv again. The problem was gone after that.

Comment: That solution may not be an option if you are working on AWS.

Comment: I was working on an azure instance, they allow to switch user to root in there console. Don't know much about AWS. Basically what i suspect is that whatever user you are using should have write access(or maybe write+execute access)

Comment: My suspicion was slightly different. I suspected that the Ubuntu repository packages for Python somehow had this bug in them. The problem fixed itself after some updates and server re-creation.

Comment: Glad that you solved it!